# Excel Shift Chart Data Series Over 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel chart with many lines and I wish to increment the y values of the lines one column over.

Essentially changing the range which currently looks like `$A$4:$A$7` to `$B$4:B$7`.

Normally if this was a chart with only one line, selecting the chart would put colored boxes over the data and you could simply drag it over one column, however with multiple lines (or series), those boxes don't show up and I would have to select each series and enter in a new data range, which with 10 lines on the same plot that needs to be done for hundreds of plots, it is a little problematic.

I have tried to find an addon that changes how the Select Data Source window works (since it is utterly unusable with large data sets)

I have tried doing this in VBA by setting the series' `y` range to a new range but `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Values = NewRange` kept giving me an "object defined" error.

I have an example file here showing a simple multiple line chart that I wish to shift the `y` ranges over.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fbc5SoLDu0z4mG6A03gsHz_z8ANnFeHc/view?usp=sharing

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code takes the active chart, and moves the series name and Y values of each series right by one column:

```
Sub MoveYright1column()
  With ActiveChart
    Dim srs As Series
    For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
      ' get series formula
      Dim sFmla As String
      sFmla = srs.Formula
      ' get arguments only
      sFmla = Mid$(Left(sFmla, Len(sFmla) - 1), InStr(sFmla, "(") + 1)
      ' split into array
      Dim vFmla As Variant
      vFmla = Split(sFmla, ",")
      ' Name address is 1st arg
      Dim sName As String
      sName = vFmla(LBound(vFmla))
      ' name range
      Dim rName As Range
      Set rName = Range(sName)
      ' offset one column
      Set rName = rName.Offset(, 1)
      srs.Name = "=" & rName.Address(, , , True)
      ' Y values address is 3rd arg
      Dim sYVals As String
      sYVals = vFmla(LBound(vFmla) + 2)
      ' Y values range
      Dim rYVals As Range
      Set rYVals = Range(sYVals)
      ' offset one column
      Set rYVals = rYVals.Offset(, 1)
      srs.Values = rYVals
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```